# Range of index in NumPy correlation function

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I am looking into the [NumPy correlation function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)

```
numpy.correlate(a, v, mode='valid')[source]
Cross-correlation of two 1-dimensional sequences.
```

This function computes the correlation as generally defined in signal processing texts:

```
c_{av}[k] = sum_n a[n+k] * conj(v[n])
```

Then for the example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
v = [0, 1, 0.5]
np.correlate([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5], "full")
array([ 0.5,  2. ,  3.5,  3. ,  0. ])
```

So the k in the output array is from 0 to 4 in this example. However, I am wondering how does a[n+k] is defined when (n+k) > 2 in this case?

Also, how is conjugate(v(n)) defined and how is each element in array computed?

Comment: (a) This is a NumPy function; not a SciPy function. (b) [Complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate); if you are not working with complex numbers, you don't need to pay attention to it. (c) "how is each element in array computed" is unclear. The arrays are given to this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula `c_{av}[k] = sum_n a[n+k] * conj(v[n])` is a little misleading because `k` on the left is not necessarily the Python index of the output array. In the 'full' mode, the possible values of `k` are those for which there exists at least one `n` such that `a[n+k] * conj(v[n])` is defined (that is, both n+k and n fall in the ranges of respective arrays).

In your examples, k in  `sum_n a[n+k] * conj(v[n])` can be -2, -1, 0, 1, 2. These generate 5 values that you see. For example, k being -2 results in `a[2-2]*conj(v[2])` which is 0.5, and so on.

In general, the range of k in the 'full' mode is from `1-len(a)` to `len(v)-1` inclusive. So, if k is really understood as Python index, then the formula should be

`c_{av}[k] = sum_n a[n+k+len(a)-1] * conj(v[n])`